# Gemfile returning lot of dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I wrote a project in Ruby on Rails and tried to deploy it. Here is the Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.github.com'

gem 'rails', '4.2.6'

gem 'rake','0.8.7'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'mysql2', '0.2.6'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.20'

# GUID generator
gem 'uuidtools', '2.1.2'

# Paperclip: for image resizing
gem 'paperclip', '2.4'

# Delayed job
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.2'

# Typus, admin interface
gem 'typus', '3.0.2'

# set attribute value to nil if blank
gem "nilify_blanks", '1.0.0'

# ssl gem
gem "bartt-ssl_requirement", "~> 1.2.7", :require => 'ssl_requirement'

# for social login
gem 'omniauth', '0.2.0'

# to detect user location
gem 'geocoder', '1.1.0'

# use to sanitize html
gem 'sanitize', '2.0.1'

# captcha for registration
gem 'recaptcha', '0.3.1', :require => "recaptcha/rails"
# base 32
gem 'base32', '0.1.3'

# amazon s3
gem 'aws-s3', '0.6.2'

#json
gem 'json', '1.7.7'

# pagination
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

# jammit for asset packaging
gem 'jammit', '0.6.3'

gem 'oniguruma'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri', "1.4.4.1"
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end

gem "fb_graph", "1.9.5"

gem 'sitemap_generator', '2.1.8'

gem 'fastercsv', "1.5.5"

# to make it the same prior to 3.018 upgrade

gem 'addressable', "2.2.4"
gem 'arel', "6.0"
gem 'attr_required', '0.0.3'

gem 'cocaine', "0.2.0"
gem 'daemons', "1.1.0"

gem 'httpclient', '2.2.1'
gem 'i18n', '0.5.0'

gem 'mail', '2.5.4'

gem 'mime-types', '1.16'
gem 'multipart-post', '1.1.0'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.4.4'
gem 'oauth', '0.4.4'
gem 'open4', '1.2.0'
gem 'polyglot', '0.3.1'
gem 'pyu-ruby-sasl', '0.0.3.2'
gem 'rack', '1.6'
gem 'rack-mount', '0.6.13'
gem 'rack-oauth2', '0.9.2'
gem 'rack-test', '0.5.6'
gem 'rest-client', '1.6.1'
gem 'ruby-openid', '2.1.8'
gem 'treetop', '1.4.9'
gem 'tzinfo', '1.1'
gem 'xml-simple', '1.0.15'
```

Then I ran `bundle update` to update the gem packages which weren't compatible with `rails 4.2.6`. I got this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
 In Gemfile:
   rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6)    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
     actionview (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
       activesupport (= 4.2.6) x86-mingw32    delayed_job (= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
     activesupport (~> 3.0)    delayed_job (= 2.1.2) was resolved to 2.1.2, which depends on
     activesupport (~> 3.0) x86-mingw32    paperclip (= 2.4) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
     activesupport (>= 2.3.2)    paperclip (= 2.4) was resolved to 2.4.0, which depends on
     activesupport (>= 2.3.2) x86-mingw32    rack-oauth2 (= 0.9.2) was resolved to 0.9.2, which depends on
     activesupport (>= 2.3)    rack-oauth2 (= 0.9.2) was resolved to 0.9.2, which depends on
     activesupport (>= 2.3) x86-mingw32
```

So I added `gem 'activesupport', '4.2.6'` to Gem file and ran `bundle update` again, but got same error. How can I fix it?

Comment: Delete your `Gemfile.lock` file and try updating once again.

Comment: That didn't help, took sometime to reply because internet is slow here and `bundle update` is taking some time to execute...

Comment: Are you using RVM?

Comment: I'm using `rbenv` which is suggested by gorails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line of the error message describes the situation: bundler can't find a version of active support that satisfies the conflicting requirements of other gems in your Gemfile. Since the problem is that bundler can't find a suitable version of active support, manually specifying a version is unlikely to help.

The rest of the message is just a list of all related dependencies to help you find the conflict. From there you can see that your Gemfile pins `delayed_job` to version 2.1.2, which in turn has a requirement that active support be ~> 3.0 which conflicts to the requirement to use rails 4.2.6.

You need to remove or update the required delayed job version. From memory, you'll need version 4.0 or higher of delayed job. Those version also split the core of delayed job from the choice of persistence backend, so you'll need to add `delayed_job_active_record` gem too. The upgrade instructions for delayed job have more details.

Comment: Excellent... I used `delayed_job` with version `4.1.2` and used `Gem 'delayed_job_active_record'`. It fixed that error. However there are other Gems which aren't compatible with rails 4.2.6. But `bundle update` cmd suggests suitable versions of non-compatible Gems... thanks a lot :)